# FirebaseException: Failed to bounce to type

Tags: android, firebase

Estou tentando fazer umas requisições de um aplicativo meu para o firebase. Consigo salvar dados no banco de dados normalmente, mas na hora de recuperá-los, encontro o seguinte erro:

> 06-20 12:07:15.151 28158-28158/sgk.com.br.sgk E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                   Process: sgk.com.br.sgk, PID: 28158
>                                                                   com.firebase.client.FirebaseException: Failed to bounce to type
>                                                                       at com.firebase.client.DataSnapshot.getValue(DataSnapshot.java:183)
>                                                                       at sgk.com.br.sgk.Activity.GreatTrainsActivity$1.onDataChange(GreatTrainsActivity.java:65)
>                                                                       at com.firebase.client.core.ValueEventRegistration.fireEvent(ValueEventRegistration.java:45)
>                                                                       at com.firebase.client.core.view.DataEvent.fire(DataEvent.java:45)
>                                                                       at com.firebase.client.core.view.EventRaiser$1.run(EventRaiser.java:38)
>                                                                       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:746)
>                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443)
>                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728)
>                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
>                                                                    Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "vdsrXOFXRZbAfmoEQ3WEVB1GDDa2" (class sgk.com.br.sgk.Others.Train), not marked as ignorable (2 known properties: , "description", "local"])
>                                                                       at [Source: java.io.StringReader@ab8ad7; line: 1, column: 34] (through reference chain: sgk.com.br.sgk.Others.Train["vdsrXOFXRZbAfmoEQ3WEVB1GDDa2"])
>                                                                       at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.reportUnknownProperty(DeserializationContext.java:555)
>                                                                       at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StdDeserializer.handleUnknownProperty(StdDeserializer.java:708)
>                                                                       at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.handleUnknownProperty(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1160)
>                                                                       at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserializeFromObject(BeanDeserializer.java:315)
>                                                                       at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:121)
>                                                                       at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:2888)
>                                                                       at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2034)
>                                                                       at com.firebase.client.DataSnapshot.getValue(DataSnapshot.java:181)
>                                                                       at sgk.com.br.sgk.Activity.GreatTrainsActivity$1.onDataChange(GreatTrainsActivity.java:65) 
>                                                                       at com.firebase.client.core.ValueEventRegistration.fireEvent(ValueEventRegistration.java:45) 
>                                                                       at com.firebase.client.core.view.DataEvent.fire(DataEvent.java:45) 
>                                                                       at com.firebase.client.core.view.EventRaiser$1.run(EventRaiser.java:38) 
>                                                                       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:746) 
>                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
>                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
>                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443) 
>                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)

Esse é o meu código

```
Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);
        Firebase ref = new Firebase(Constants.FIREBASE_URL);

        ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                    //Getting the data from snapshot
                    Train train = postSnapshot.getValue(Train.class);
                    //Adding it to a string
                    String string = "Local: " + train.getLocal() + "\nDescrição: " + train.getDescription() + "\n\n";
                    //Displaying it on textview
                    textViewPersons.setText(string);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
                System.out.println("The read failed: " + firebaseError.getMessage());
            }
        });
```

E essa é minha POJO

```
public class Train {

private String local;
private String description;

public Train() {
}

public String getLocal() {
    return local;
}

public void setLocal(String local) {
    this.local = local;
}

public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}
```

Comment: caramba, vei, tecnologia novissima, tirei a implementação porque tive problemas, publiquei as novas versoes sem isso, vou esperar mais uns dias pra atualizar com a api...
se voce resolver, poste aqui, pode ajudar e muito...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você está tentando acessar o nó raiz do firebase, ele possui outros nós além do Train. O retorno está te dizendo que não é possível transformar o objeto json recebido do firebase para o seu Pojo. Ou seja, seu pojo espera apenas o no Train mas está recebendo todos os nós que estão no mesmo nível de train, no caso o nó users. Você deve navegar para o filho do nó raiz que seria o seu nó train.
para isso usa-se o método ***child("nome nó")***

Tente isto:

```
ref.child("Train").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                    //Getting the data from snapshot
                    Train train = postSnapshot.getValue(Train.class);
                    //Adding it to a string
                    String string = "Local: " + train.getLocal() + "\nDescrição: " + train.getDescription() + "\n\n";
                    //Displaying it on textview
                    textViewPersons.setText(string);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
                System.out.println("The read failed: " + firebaseError.getMessage());
            }
        });
```

Comment: Exatamente isso! Obrigado Caique

Answer (score 1):

Me parece que o Firebase usa o Jackson por padrão para fazer a conversão dos objetos Json/String e vice versa, portanto, é obrigatório ao Jackson que sua classe tenha a implementação do método toString() para representação em String do objeto (caso não tenha um parser específico como seu código mostra).

Exemplo:

```
@Override
  public String toString() { return "Train{local='"+local+“', description='"+description+"'}”; }
```

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda. Porém na documentação do firebase não a nada relacionado a isso e acabei descobrindo que o problema era outro, como explanei na minha resposta. Obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Descobri qual era o problema.

O Json do banco de dados do Firebase possuia os usuário registrados na aplicação. Segue o código

```
    {
  "Train" : {
    "description" : "dbdjem",
    "local" : "shsusn"
  },
  "users" : {
    "f01dfa18-54ac-41ea-97ff-97d0e40b872b" : {
      "email" : "gui@email.com"
    },
    "vdsrXOFXRZbAfmoEQ3WEVB1GDDa2" : {
      "email" : "leo@email.com"
    }
  }
}
```

Foi só apagar do banco os usuários e deixar somente essa parte do json e a aplicação funcionou normalmente.

```
   {
  "Train" : {
    "description" : "hdjdjdnd",
    "local" : "udjdjdjd"
  }
}
```

Comment: Legal Leonardo! Obrigado por colocar a resposta.